# Want to Understand @ManyToMany relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one entity.
Can any one explain the relationship of predecessor and successor which i have defined in entity?

Like 
I have multiple steps 
Step 1,Step 2,Step 3,Step 4,Step 5

and we only come in that step from it's predecessor 
so for T_DATA_STEP table data is like below 
predecessor of Step 5 is = step 4 , step 3
predecessor of Step 4 is = step 3 
predecessor of Step 3 is = step 2 
predecessor of Step 2 is = step 1 
there is no predecessor for step 1

Now my entity is like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DATA_STEP")
public class DataStepEntity implements DBEntity, Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "DATA_STEP_ID", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "DATA_STEP_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = DataStepEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_WKF_PREDECESSOR", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_STEP_ID"))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<DataStepEntity> predecessor;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="predecessor",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<DataStepEntity> successor;

}
```

So my Question is that  
When I get the  DataStepEntity for Step 4 then it will give me predecessor as step 3 and successor as step 5 in hibernate. 
I want to understand the whole fetching of successor. 
How It will bind the step 5 as successor of Step 4?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DataStepEntity`, there is a reflexive `@ManyToMany` relationship for the successors. There will be a `JoinTable` with two foreign keys to the `T_DATA_STEP` table (the table for the DataStepEntity entity). One column will be the Id of the `DataStepEntity` and the other the Id of its successor.

Each `DataStepEntity` will have an entry in this table for each successor. For example, if your Step4 has only one successor, Step5, there will be an entry with the Id of Step4 in the IDs column and the ID of Step5 in the successors ID column.

The process is the same as `@ManyToMany` relationships pointing to different entities, but the foreign keys in the `JoinTable` created points to the same table.

For the predecessor case, it is the same as successor. There will be another JoinTable with the IDs of the DataStepEntities and their predecessors.